# Kickstarting with noflo-nodejs --graph <json file> --batch --register false

Tags: javascript, node.js, noflo

I would like to use a command line in a script to run a noflo graph for testing purposes.  My graph and custom component load and execute correctly when I run them from the browser GUI, however, I cannot get them to run outside the GUI.

Noflo-nodejs looks like it should execute the graph using this command:
**node node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs --graph mygraph.json --batch --register false**

However, although it comes up, it does not appear to execute and it also does not exit.  It sits there with this output: 
node node_modules/.bin/noflo-nodejs --graph mygraph.json --batch --register false 
Loading main graph: /Users/glenna/src/noflo-rdf-pipeline/mygraph.json
NoFlo runtime listening at ws://10.88.12.0:3569
Using /Users/glenna/src/noflo-rdf-pipeline for component loading
Live IDE URL: http://app.flowhub.io#runtime/endpoint?protocol%3Dwebsocket%26address%3Dws%3A%2F%2F10.88.12.0%3A3569

I have tried using both the core/kick and core/repeat components in front of my graph to force them to start, but that did not help.

Is there some special feature I am missing?  Is this simply not supported for json?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `--debug=true`, do you see any packets transmitted? NoFlo components don't act until they receive something, so you usually need some IIPs to get the process started

Comment: There was a problem in my component start up.  I have fixed it.  Thank you.